# Use a "x-dom-event-stream" stream in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, streaming

HTML5 draft contains an API called [EventSource](http://dev.w3.org/html5/eventsource/) to stream data (notifications) trough javascript using only one server call.

Looking it up, I found an exemple on [Opera Labs](http://labs.opera.com/news/2006/09/01/) of the javascript part :

```
document.getElementsByTagName("event-source")[0]
        .addEventListener("server-time", eventHandler, false);

function eventHandler(event)
{
    // Alert time sent by the server
    alert(event.data); 
}
```

and the server side part :

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/x-dom-event-stream");
while(true) {
    echo "Event: server-time\n";
    $time = time();
    echo "data: $time\n";
    echo "\n";
    flush();
    sleep(3);
}
?>
```

But as of today, it seems only Opera has implemented the API, neither Chrome nor Safari have a working version (Am I wrong here ?)

So my question is, is there any other way in javascript, maybe more complex, to use this one stream to get data ?

EDIT : I'm looking at Comet stuff right now, but I'm not sure how to reuse that :)
EDIT 2 : Apparentry, "x-dom-event-stream" has now been renamed "text/event-stream"
EDIT 3 : Got to understand way more of it with this [recent article](http://today.java.net/article/2010/03/31/html5-server-push-technologies-part-1) from javanet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Orbited](http://orbited.org/), which provides a javascript library and the server.  The javascript library tries to use WebSockets and falls back to long-polling or other methods.

Here's a good guide: http://thingsilearned.com/2009/08/03/starting-out-with-comet-orbited-part-3-%E2%80%93-the-client/

Answer (score 0):

Well, Google is really my friend, after a long search, i found this script from Ericson Labs (?!)

https://labs.ericsson.com/apis/eventsource/

From their page :

> The EventSource enabler allows you to
>   use the upcoming Event Source API in
>   any current web browser. Simply
>   include the enabler library in your
>   page, and you are able to use the API.
>   When user agents implement the Event
>   Source API themselves, your
>   application will immediately and
>   transparently start using the native
>   implementation.

However this solution requires an API key from Ericsson, and cannot be used for a commercial application, which is not the best solution for me :(

So if you have a better approach..

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Kaazing Open Gateway](http://www.kaazing.org).  I believe it works similarly to the ericsson api in that it transparently switches to using the native implementation as it becomes available.  I think it provides both eventsource and websockets.

Comment: This is a java server, I'm looking for the javascript client.
But I'll have a look at their XMPP javascript client.